# <label for> bound to the name attribute instead of the id attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, label

I wonder if it's possible (by jQuery or other method) to have the `<label for>` attribute bound to the input by the `name` attribute instead of the `id` attribute?

The regular way:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="element_id" name="element_name">
<label for="element_id">Checkbox</label>
```

What I need to do:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="element_id" name="element_name">
<label for="element_name">Checkbox</label>
```

Comment: `$('label[for="element_name"]').attr('for', 'element_id')` but I don't see why it can't point to the id in the first place.

Comment: So simple and elegant, thanks a lot! I'm working with a client that uses an really old, outdated CMS for some auto generated forms. The CMS, poorly enough, is using the id's for system tasks, leaving me no other option than forcing the for attribute to use the name instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion from JJJ above works semantically, but when it comes to applying CSS I found it better (and less hacky) to drop the use of `<label>` entirely, and instead do the styling via custom tags, eg. `<customlabel>Label text</customlabel>`.

The `<customlabel>` can be targeted from css by eg. `[type="radio"]:checked + customlabel:before {}`.